# ln2 const value in _math.c in cpython

Tags: python, cpython

I'm looking at [_math.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_math.c) in git (line 25):

```
#if !defined(HAVE_ACOSH) || !defined(HAVE_ASINH)
static const double ln2 = 6.93147180559945286227E-01;
static const double two_pow_p28 = 268435456.0; /* 2**28 */
```

and I noticed that ln2 value is different from the what [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln(2)) value for ln2. (bald part is the difference)

ln2 = 0.693147180559945**286227** (cpython)

ln2 = 0.693147180559945**3094172321214581** (wolframalpha)

ln2 = 0.693147180559945**309417232121458** (wikipedia)

so my question is why there is a difference? what am I missing?

Comment: Educated guess: Converting decimal representations of a number to the internal IEEE754 format are only precise up to about 15 to 17 decimal digits. So this may be the best approximation of ln(2) which can be expressed in C source code for a double value.

Comment: `Decimal.from_float(math.log(2))` gives the 28622 digits that were hard-coded, proving that this value is the 64 bits ieee-754 approximation converted to decimals and truncated at a higher order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user2357112 noted, this code came from FDLIBM.  That was carefully written for IEEE-754 machines, where C doubles have 53 bits of precision.  It doesn't really care what the actual log of 2 is, but cares a whole lot about the best 53-bit approximation to `log(2)`.

To reproduce the intended 53-bit-precise value, [17 decimal digits would have sufficed](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/).

So why did they use 21 decimal digits instead?  My guess:  21 decimal digits is the minimum needed to guarantee that the converted result will be correct to 64 bits of precision.  Which *may* have been an issue at the time, if a compiler somehow decided to convert the literal to a Pentium's 80-bit float format (which has 64 bits of precision).

So they displayed the 53-bit result with enough decimal digits so that *if* it were converted to a binary float format with 64 bits of precision, the trailing 11 bits (=64-53) would all be zeroes, thus ensuring they'd be working with the 53-bit value they intended from the start.

```
>>> import mpmath
>>> x = mpmath.log(2)
>>> x
mpf('0.69314718055994529')
>>> mpmath.mp.prec = 64
>>> y = mpmath.mpf("0.693147180559945286227")
>>> x == y
True
>>> y
mpf('0.693147180559945286227')
```

In English, `x` is the 53-bit precise value of `log(2)`, and `y` is the result of converting the decimal string in the code to a binary float format with 64 bits of precision.  They're identical.

In current reality, I expect all compilers now convert the literal to the native IEEE-754 double format, with 53 bits of precision.

Either way, the code ensures the best 53-bit approximation to `log(2)` will be used.

Comment: It seems to me that whatever the reason to encode 21 digits, it is better to encode the actual mathematical digits. This is more robust with respect to variable precision.

Comment: Except FDLIBM had no intent to deal with "variable precision" :  it's carefully and cleverly written throughout to give high-quality results on boxes with IEEE-754 conforming arithmetic.  This effects everything from, e.g., the constants used, through the number of terms used in polynomial and rational approximation, to the precise sequence of operations used.  There are _many_ places in its code that rely on having exactly 53 bits of precision, and on that the arithmetic does best-possible rounding.  Variable precision requires different _algorithms_, not just different constants.

Answer (score 4):

Up to the precision of binary64 floating-point representation, these values are equal:

```
In [21]: 0.6931471805599453094172321214581 == 0.693147180559945286227
Out[21]: True
```

`0.693147180559945286227` is what you get if you store the most accurate representable approximation of ln(2) into a 64-bit float and then print it to that many digits. Trying to stuff more digits in a float just gets the result rounded to the same value:

```
In [23]: '%.21f' % 0.6931471805599453094172321214581
Out[23]: '0.693147180559945286227'
```

As for why they wrote `0.693147180559945286227` in the code, you'd have to ask the guys who wrote [FDLIBM](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_acosh.c) at Sun back in 1993. This code came from FDLIBM.

Answer (score 3):

Python seems wrong, although I'm not sure it is an oversight or it has a deeper meaning. The explanation of BlackJack seems reasonable, but I don't understand, why they would give additional digits that are wrong.

You can check this yourself by using the formula under [More efficient series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Power_series). In Mathematica, you can calculate it up to 70 (35 summands) with

```
log2 = 2*Sum[1/i*(1/3)^i, {i, 1, 70, 2}]

(*
79535292197135923776615186805136682215642574454974413288086/
114745171628462663795273979107442710223059517312975273318225
*)
```

With `N[log2,30]` you get the correct digits

```
0.693147180559945309417232121458
```

which supports the correctness of Wikipedia and W|A. If you like, you can do the same calculation for machine precision numbers. In Mathematica, this usually means `double`.

```
logC = Compile[{{z, _Real, 0}},
  2.0*Sum[1/i*((z - 1)/(z + 1))^i, {i, 1, 100, 2}]
]
```

Note that this code gets completely compiled to a normal iteration and does not use some error reducing summation scheme. So there is no magical compiled `Sum` function. This gives on my machine:

```
logC[2]//FullForm
(* 0.6931471805599451` *)
```

and is correct up to the digits you pointed out. This has the precision that was suggested by BlackJack

```
$MachinePrecision
(* 15.9546 *)
```

### Edit

As pointed out in comments and answers, the value you see in `_math.c` might be the 53 bit representation

```
digits = RealDigits[log2, 2, 53];
N[FromDigits[digits, 2], 21]

(*  0.693147180559945286227 *)
```